# mysql - find unique users across all sites

Tags: mysql, sql

I have user table which has below data:

```
user_id      site_unique_id    user_email
1            1                 steve@gmail.com
2            2                 steve@gmail.com
3            3                 steve@gmail.com
4            1                 mark@gmail.com
5            3                 mark@gmail.com
6            1                 jack@gmail.com
7            2                 jack@gmail.com
8            3                 jack@gmail.com
9            1                 smith@gmail.com
10           2                 smith@gmail.com
```

I want to make mysql query to get user emails that exist in all 3 sites i.e.

```
email_id           site_unique_id
steve@gmail.com    1,2,3
jack@gmail.com     1,2,3
```

in above data mark & jack are not exist in site 2 & 3 respectively those emails not needed in sql result.

Comment: . . "5 sites"?  Your question only refers to *three* sites.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want users that are in all *three* sites.  If so:

```
select user_email, group_concat(site_unique_id order by site_unique_id) as sites
from t
group by user_email
having count(*) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

use group_concat and having

```
select user_email, group_concat(site_unique_id SEPARATOR ',')
from tablename
group by user_email
having count(*)=3
```